# throw-away Windows installation to work on hardware hackathons

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, unix, hardware-virtualization

I'm a UNIX dev, but sometimes there are interesting hardware-related hackathons that require using useless Windows-only SDKs in order to participate fully; this would also require USB access, too.

I do have a Windows laptop, often for thin-client purposes, however, I don't like installing random stuff onto it.

Are there any easy ways to get disposable Windows instances for such events?  I'm thinking of perhaps using an external HDD, and duplicating the primary Windows install, and/or the original disc image that would come with a new ThinkPad laptop, onto an external HDD, with the use of UNIX [dd(1)](http://mdoc.su/-/dd.1) tool, to be used on the same laptop by dual-booting from a USB drive.  Will this work at all, or would various copy-protection features and/or other issues (around drive letters etc) prevent this from working as intended?

Or are there perhaps some other hardware virtualisation solutions that would let you get disposable Windows instances that would still have full unfettered access to the USB ports of the laptop, as if the port was native to the instance?

Comment: Could you virtualise the windows instance on your laptop, and assign a USB device to the VM? It would allow you to snapshot back to a fresh install easily.
Also, do you need a full install of Windows? You could quite easily run Windows 10 IOT on a Raspberry Pi and remote into it.

Comment: [Windows Sandbox](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+sandbox) potentially of use here?

Comment: Yes, Sandbox sounds like exactly what I'd be looking for, the only issue being is the question of whether or not it actually supports USB. Although looking more into the descr, the requirement of having Windows Pro seems misguided — I went with Home, as Pro was only supposed to have Enterprise-level features; and a Sandbox has nothing to do with Enterprise, TBH, it's something that any developer enthusiast would want to have in their arsenal, unlike the rest of the supposed benefits of Pro that would hardly be useful outside of Enterprise.